# How to add click event to a dynamically created anchor tag in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, anchor

My requirement is to first convert a part of plain text to a link and then attach a click handler to it. On click of that link, a popup should open with some details to show.

To convert that normal string to a link, I've used below code, but I'm unable to attach a click event listener to it.

```
   const arrayLabel = text.split('$');
   let stylizedText = arrayLabel[0];
   stylizedText += `<a id="anchorId" style="text-decoration: none;" href="javascript:void(0)">${arrayLabel[1]}</a> `;
   stylizedText += arrayLabel[2];
   return stylizedText;
```

I tried to add `(click)="myMethod"` and `document.getElementById('anchorId").addEventListener('click','myMethod')`,but both approaches failed.
Can anyone please help here?

Comment: To use `document.getElementById("anchorId")` you have to append `stylizedText` to the DOM first. Alternatively you could use `document.createElement('a')` and skip the later lookup. Since this seems to be part of a code / function, it is hard to help you specifically.

Comment: Thanks Lain for your response, I even tried creating the anchor tag using the way you suggested above but still i couldnt see the click event attached in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for this using ngAfterViewInit in angular.

```
  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    const anchor = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#anchorId');
    if (anchor) {
      anchor.addEventListener('click', () => {
           // Do your task
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).